# как подтянуть созданный FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, github, fxml

```
package ru.parsertwo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class StartmenuFX extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        AnchorPane panel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("startmenuFX.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(panel, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

в том же пакете лежит fxml

**startmenuFX.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane  fx:controller="ru.parsertwo.StartmenuFX" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <BorderPane layoutX="1.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <top>
            <Pane prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="226.0" layoutY="6.0" text="Укажите путь к файлу" />
                  <Button layoutX="332.0" layoutY="24.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Обзор" />
                  <Label layoutX="158.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="151.0" />
               </children>
            </Pane>
         </top>
         <center>
            <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
              <columns>
              </columns>
            </TableView>
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Почему то не запускается  заливал на гитхаб у других работает , что у меня не так? [Проект на github](https://github.com/AlexandrKaleganov/parsefile).

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:941)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3246)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
    at ru.parsertwo.StartmenuFX.start(StartmenuFX.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application ru.parsertwo.StartmenuFX
```

Comment: Распологать `fxml` файлы в том же пакете - в чем смысл этого подхода? Для этого есть директория `resources`. Расположите файлы общепринятым способом: `resources/ru/parsertwo/startmenuFX.fxml`

Comment: да какая разница всёравно не пашет

Comment: я сам проверял, работает. Прям вот с приведенным вами кодом. Откройте через проводник папку `resources` и убедитесь что в ней есть папка `ru`, а в папке `ru` есть папка `parsertwo` (в проекте папка `resources` находится на одном уровне с `java`)